# Code analysis for yaml based files using SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using **Sonarqube 6.7** version and trying to analyze YAML based files using **SonarQube**. I installed the **SonarQube YAML plugin(v1.4.2)** and I couldn't find any document to enable the analysis. When I tried to search, this is the only document that I found on the web(https://github.com/sbaudoin/sonar-yaml). It's not helping me much. Please help with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this image will show, but you can enable this by first choosing it as a Quality
Profile. This is assuming you already downloaded the jar and added it to your /extensions/plugins directory. It should give you the option of choosing Yaml. After this you have the option of either choosing to activate additional rules for the default profile 
"Sonar way" or create a custom profile when logged in as admin.
[QualityProfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lw5o.png)

Comment: In order for it to show up for my project scan I did have to add an inclusion. mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.inclusions="**/\*.yaml"